# Encryption of Web.Config

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, encryption, web-config

I **encrypted** part of my **web.config** of my **web application** by following this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100).aspx

But when I try to Debug it says:

"*Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section Espacio.*"

It´s pretty obvious that that part cannot be read, but what should I do ?

I´ve never used anything related to **encryption**

Regards.